# Password protect controls (not locking)

Tags: keyboard, mouse, security

I search for a way to lock the controls (mouse and keyboard) while still showing the applications on the screen.
I think about something where I press an  key combination to de/-activate the mode and to deactivate I need a password

Comment: We've been given no details as to your OS/product/release, are you hoping we guess correctly?  Why not tell us?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the [`xtrlock`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/xtrlock.1x.html) package, which is available from the Ubuntu official repositories.

**First**, install it with:

```bash
sudo apt install xtrlock
```

**Then**, create your keyboard shortcut in:

Settings -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts -> Add Shortcut and add:

```sh
sh -c 'sleep 1 && xtrlock'
```

in the shortcut's "command" field.

**Finally**, you activate it with your chosen key shortcut and deactivate it with simply pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> then typing your password and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I was looking for